# How To Refresh Data Every Time Opening The Page In React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Current Code**

*App.js*

```js
const Mypage = {
  screen: MypageScreen,
  navigationOptions: () => ({
    headerShown: false,
  }),
};

const MypageStack = createStackNavigator(
  { Mypage },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Mypage',
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Mypage',
    },
  },
);

const postLoginNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Mypage: MypageStack,
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Loading,
  ...,
  PostLogin: postLoginNavigator,
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

*Mypage.js*

```js
export default class Mypage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: '',
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // getting how many items this user have
    const items = await db.getAllItems()
    // items is an array
    this.setState({
      items: items.length,
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Items</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>
          { this.state.items }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I want the datas to be refreshed When every time I open mypage tab.

The number of items in mypage.js is changing, so I want updated number of items.

Or when only number of items changes, I want updated number.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

As looking into your code you are using **react-navigation v4** maybe, So you have to add Event Listener for every focus on the tab it will be called and will fetch new data.

```
componentDidMount() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
  // The screen is focused
  // Call any action
});
```

}

For more information about events have a look at this.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-a-didfocus-event-listener

Answer (score 0):

For just checking number of items, you can always use `items.length`, but if you are looking for the case when your state should actually get updated data you can use `shouldComponentUpdate`

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  return nextState.items != this.state.items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So should I use shouldComponentUpdate instead of using componentDidMount?

Comment: No, you didnt understand, shouldComponentUpdate has different purpose. Please check this documentation link https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate